# SQL Server query to show last activity time for current session

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, session

Back end: SQL Server 2017 Express

Front End: Microsoft Access 2019 with ODBC linked tables to the SQL Server database

Objective: To detect inactivity of say 30 minutes in the current session, and then exit from Access

I would like a SQL Server query (to be called from the front-end Access database, via a timer) which will return the date/time of the last SQL statement (e.g. select/insert/update/delete) for the current session, so that the Access application can exit after a defined period of inactivity.

So far, I have looked at sp_who, sp_who2, sysprocesses, dm_exec_connections, dm_db_index_usage_stats and dm_exec_sessions.

Whilst these return useful looking columns such as LastBatch, the problem is that the act of querying the database updates the return value. For instance, if I run sp_who2 and look at the row for my SPID, the value of LastBatch is always the same as GetDate().

I know that the options above would work if I was monitoring another session (SPID) but I'm looking for a way to find the time of last activity (excluding sp_who2 etc) **for my own session**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Gonna be difficult: `select s.last_request_end_time from sys.dm_exec_sessions s where s.session_id=@@SPID` always returns the current time

Comment: What you are trying to do won't work. Access maintains multiple connections to SQL Server. Therefore multiple SPID's.You need to get the info for the login, not the SPID. BingGoogle for last query by login. There will be many results.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the last request time is the time of the request requesting the last request time.  (Had to write that.)  Maybe you should be detecting if Access is idle instead?  Searching "automatically close access if idle" has promising results.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/miscellaneous/detect-user-idle-time-or-inactivity

https://www.iaccessworld.com/set-program-close-automatically/

https://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=1432

If you absolutely have to do the check in SQL Server, then perhaps a job that checks connections.  It can kill connections if they are idle a while without an open transaction.  I don't know if the access connections will be obvious as not all apps provide their name.  I also don't know how the access front end will respond.  I'd be leery of doing this.

Comment: Thank you. I had initially considered the Access Active Form Name and Active Control Name approach, but SQL Server had seemed a better choice (as some Access forms will be processing long running updates without the control changing). If I was using a non-Express version of SQL Server I could run a job frequently to populate a table which I could then query from Access. However, AVG's comment about the SPID changing would make this challenging too. Looks like the Access route is the way to go. Thanks for the links to those solutions.